# How to create a one array having after insertion of every element from foreach loop in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

How to create a array containing all the questions detail in following scenario?

```
foreach($question_ids as $question_id) {
        /** fetch the question data by question id **/
        list($data) = prepare_response($objQuestions->GetQuestionByID($question_id));  
      }
```

Can anyone please help me in this regard?

Comment: I think you need to explain your problem in a bit more detail.  It really isn't clear what you're asking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this?

```
$questionData = array();

foreach($question_ids as $question_id) {
    /** fetch the question data by question id **/
    list($data) = prepare_response($objQuestions->GetQuestionByID($question_id)); 
    $questionData[$question_id] = $data; 
}

var_dump($questionData);
```

Although I should note that if `$objQuestions->GetQuestionByID` is running a query, then you're going about this the wrong way as running a query inside a loop is not recommended.